# http-request from Button VS from Class

Tags: android, class, button, broadcastreceiver, http-request

i got a class i made, that makes a simple GET request and displays toast messege with the response...

if i call the function from a bottom event click it displays the messege with the data returned, just ok.

but if i call the same function from a brodcast reciver class, it just showing the massege with the data '' (null)

i belive that it showing the massege before i could get the data, and with the button it waits for the data..

how can i make it work from the brodcast reciver?

the class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myclass{


public static void doHttpRequest(String param1, Context context){

    String ret="";

     try {
         URL url = new URL("http://website.com/page?param="+param1);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
        ret=readStream(con.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CharSequence text = "return data-  "+ret;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();   
}



  private static String readStream(InputStream in) {
BufferedReader reader = null;
String line = "";
String alllines = "";
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    alllines=alllines+line;
    }

    return alllines;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
      try {
        reader.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

}
return alllines;

 } 
 }
```

from the button it works fine:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

 myclass.doHttpRequest("blabla", getBaseContext());

 }});
```

from the brodcast reciver witch in different class it won't return data, but shows the toast..

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    myclass.doHttpRequest("blabla", context);


    break;
   } }


    }
```

please HELP.... :) THANKS

Answer (score 0):

All fixed.. it's seems to be a project settings error, or premmisions error (but i had the premissions in the manifest... must not apply in the apk while compiling)

i copied the classes to enother project made by erlier version of eclipse, and it's works there like a charm...

thanks anyway..
i tried for hours to fix it in the code.. and it was the settings....

Comment: Tip:

`public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)`
This method is always called within the main thread of its process, unless you explicitly asked for it to be scheduled on a different thread using registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter, String, android.os.Handler). When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running operations in it.

Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a `myclass.java` and `CustomBroadcastReceiver.java` and tried your code by removing the break statement and one extra curly brace from the `CustomBroadcastReceiver.java` class and it worked fine for me.

The following code in Activity class demonstrates registering, uninteresting receiver and a Handler for a sample/test broadcast.

```
CustomBroadcastReceiver customBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    customBroadcastReceiver = new CustomBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(cusoBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.app.testbroadcast"));

            // For test broadcast only.
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.app.testbroadcast"));
        }
    }, 2000);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(customBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Hope this helps.